# Accessing api data in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Given data from an API

```
async getStudentDetail(){


  try {
    const response = await Object.freeze(
      axios.get("/student/"+this.id+"/")
    );

    this.student = response.data
    this.parent = response.data.parent
    
    
    
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.response);
  }
  }
```

The student variable now holds this

```
 {
"id": 1,
"parent": {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Michael",
    "last_name": "Smith",
},     books: [{"id": 1, "name": "Counting Blessings"},{"id": 2,"name": "Breakaway"}]}
```

I can iterate through the books by calling

```
v-for"student.books"
```

But can't access the parent name with

```
{{student.parent.name}}
```

In Vue 2, I could put this in a variable boy, and access the parent's first name by calling

```
boy.parent.first_name
```

But I can't do that for some reason on Vue 3, I don't know if I'm doing something wrong. But the weird thing is if I put the parent in a different variable directly from the response like this

```
this.parent = response.data.parent
```

I am able to access the parent values from this new variable. What exactly am I doing wrong? Cos I didn't seem to have this issue in Vue 2. Am I missing something? This is my first time working with Vue 3, that's why I am just thinking it might be it, but don't really think so.

Comment: Show us your code for fetching the response and how you use that response.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is caused by the asynchronous handling.
In vue2, if you call the method `getStudentDetail` in the `onMouted` or `beforeMounted` option, the call will be resolved before the view is rendered. So, the `student` does not contain data yet. (I don't use vue2, forgive me if I'm wrong)

In vue3, there is only `setup` method. If you need to make sure the call done before the view is rendered, you need to put the call in the same hook as vue 2:
https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#lifecycle-hooks

```
  setup() {
    onMounted(async () => {
      await getStudentDetail();
    })
  }
}
```

Another way is to use reactive variables instead. So, the view will be updated when the async method is resolved.
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactivity-fundamentals